# How to expand records based on start and end date in SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

My Source Looks like this

```
ID    Name      Start_Date   End_ate
1     John      3-Aug-2017   30-Nov-2017
2     Nikhil    1-Jul-2017   31-Oct-2017
```

I want to expand these records based on `start_Date` and `End_date` i.e. For every entry in the above source table, return a separate DATE_ID for every day between `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` so something like this

```
ID     Name    Date_ID
1      John    3-Aug-2017
1      John    4-Aug-2017
1      John    5-Aug-2017
.
.
.
1     John    30-Nov-2017
2     Nikhil  1-Jul-2017
2     Nikhil  2-Jul-2017
.
.
.
2    Nikhil  31-Oct-2017
```

Since start and end date for each record is not fixed so I am not sure how to implement this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How you calculate between dates in this type. If it is in date time format only  possible

Comment: What is your table name ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you are, replace [a] with [your_table_name] :

```
SELECT (a.Start_Date + ROWNUM - 1) Date_ID, a.ID, a.Name
  FROM all_objects, a
 WHERE ROWNUM <= TO_DATE(a.End_Date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') -
       TO_DATE(a.Start_Date, 'dd-mon-yyyy') + 1;
```